# Load data from Big query to Postgre cloud sql database everyday

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I have some tables to load from big query to Postgre cloud sql database. I need to do this everyday and create some stored procedures in cloud sql. What is the best way to load tables from big query to cloud sql everyday? What are the costing implications for transferring the data and keeping cloud sql on 24/7? Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
J.

Comment: For pricing information use the pricing calculator. https://cloud.google.com/pricing

Comment: Depends on several things: mainly the data location and  volume

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Volume is not very high, may be less than 500 mb. there are 10 tables  and location is australia. Only thing is I need to push the tables everyday and be able to automate it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, a Cloud SQL database is up full time to serve request anytime. It's not a serverless product that can start when a request comes in. You can have a look to the pricing page to calculate the cost (mainly: CPU, Memory and Storage. Size database according to your usage and expected performances)

About the process, we did that in my previous company:

- Use a cloud scheduler to trigger a Cloud Functions

  - Create temporary table in BigQuery
  - Export BigQuery temporary tables to CSV in Cloud Storage
- Run a [Cloud SQL import of the files from GCS](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing) in temporary tables
- Run a request in database to merge the imported data to the existing one, and to delete the table of imported data

If it takes too much time to perform that in only one functions, you can use Cloud Run (60 minutes of time out), or a dispatch functions. This functions is called by the Cloud Scheduler and will publish a message in PubSUb for each table to process. On PubSub, you can plug a Cloud Functions (or a Cloud Run) that will perform the previous process only on the table mentioned in the message. Like that, you process concurrently all the tables and not sequentially.

---

About cost you will pay

- BigQuery query (volume of data that you process to create temporary tables)
- BigQuery storage (very low, you can create temporary table that expire (automatically deleted) after 1h)
- Cloud Storage storage (very low, you can set a lifecycle on the file, to delete them after few days)
- File transfer: free if you stay in the same region.
- Export and import: free

In summary, only the BigQuery query and the Cloud SQL instance are major costs.

Comment: Thanks for responding. So, we need python code for doing this in cloud function?

Comment: Yes, but it's small piece of code. I'm sure you can find and assemble piece of tutorial, getting started and Sstack Overflow code to achieve what you want